# detect a peak in a continuous feed of numerical data

Tags: machine-learning

This is a "very simplified" example of what I'm trying to do and I'm new to machine learning.

I have continuous feed of numerical data coming in as input. And I want to detect a specific change in the data, like a peak in a heart beat monitor.

[image]

How would I go about to accomplish this using machine learning ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you are calling a peak. You can try something like this, if you call a peak value rising on 10 points or more:

```
import numpy as np
min_peak_diff = 10
arr = np.array([3,5,10,42,4,3,6,66,8,12,7,5])
ind = np.add(np.where(arr[1:] >= arr[:-1] + min_peak_diff), 1)
print('peak indexes:', ind)
print('peak values:', arr[ind])
```

Result:

```
peak indexes: [[3 7]]
peak values: [[42 66]]
```

But if you really want to use machine learning methods you can look at:

- scikit-learn page about this topic (it has plenty of methods) https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection
- Python Outlier Detection library https://github.com/yzhao062/pyod

Comment: thanks, but as I said, I'm trying to do it using machine learning

Comment: I added some links

Comment: Interesting ! can I train it to detect different types of anomalies ?